# Como fechar um Excel application em C #

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-excel

Tenho essa função c# que converte um arquivo excel em outro formato excel, o problema é que quando o aplicativo é executado ele não encerra com a função _app.quit();

A aplicação excel é iniciada nesse trecho de código: `var _app = new Excel.Application();`

Ela inicia três processos:

[image: Gerenciador de tarefas - processo]

Eu não tenho o Excel instalado na minha máquina, uso o WPS Oficce 2019, um sofware alternativo, gratuito.

Como encerro essa aplicação?

```
    private void Convert_CSV_To_Excel()
{
    try
    {
        // Rename .csv To .xlsm
        System.IO.File.Move(File, File);

        var _app = new Excel.Application();
        var _workbooks = _app.Workbooks;

        _workbooks.OpenText(File,
                                 DataType: Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
                                 TextQualifier: Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone,
                                 ConsecutiveDelimiter: true,
                                 Semicolon: true);

        // Convert To Excle 97 / 2003
        _workbooks[1].SaveAs(File + "OK.xlsm", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled);
        _workbooks.Close();
        _app.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: [Isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930307/why-does-microsoft-office-interop-excel-application-quit-leave-the-background) pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

```
_workbooks.Close(0);
_app.Quit();
```

ou então

```
_workbooks.Close(true);
```